# Python - How can I avoid duplicates (list)?

Tags: python

```
import random
d = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
for i in range(1, 13):
    d[i] = random.randint(0,10)
    print(d)

for i in range(10):            
    perturbdp = random.randint(1,12)
    d[perturbdp] = random.randint(0,10)
    print(perturbdp)
    print(d)
```

Output:

```
[0, 3, 5, 1, 2, 2, 10, 0, 8, 0, 4, 8, 8]
8
[0, 3, 5, 1, 2, 2, 10, 0, 7, 0, 4, 8, 8]
10
[0, 3, 5, 1, 2, 2, 10, 0, 7, 0, 9, 8, 8]
9
[0, 3, 5, 1, 2, 2, 10, 0, 7, 2, 9, 8, 8]
10
[0, 3, 5, 1, 2, 2, 10, 0, 7, 2, 6, 8, 8]
12
[0, 3, 5, 1, 2, 2, 10, 0, 7, 2, 6, 8, 8]
12
[0, 3, 5, 1, 2, 2, 10, 0, 7, 2, 6, 8, 2]
8
[0, 3, 5, 1, 2, 2, 10, 0, 8, 2, 6, 8, 2]
6
[0, 3, 5, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 8, 2, 6, 8, 2]
7
[0, 3, 5, 1, 2, 2, 1, 6, 8, 2, 6, 8, 2]
10
[0, 3, 5, 1, 2, 2, 1, 6, 8, 2, 6, 8, 2]
```

I have created random lists as per the code.

When I iterate to generate further by picking some position, it picks and replaces the value with the same value. Please look last 3 lines from output section.
It has picked position 10 and it replaced with 6 again. How can we avoid this?

Comment: keep drawing until the value is different from original?

Comment: I don't understand. When I iterate, I am expecting there should not be any of the old strings.

Answer (score 2):

Repeat until it's different from the current value:

```
for i in range(10):            
    perturbdp = random.randint(1,12)
    new_value = random.randint(0,10)
    while new_value == d[perturbdp]:
        new_value = random.randint(0,10)
    d[perturbdp] = new_value
    print(perturbdp)
    print(d)
```

If you don't want any repetition among your outputs, you will want to iterate over all possible combinations:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
import random

comb = combinations_with_replacement(range(11), 13) # all 13-elements combinations of int between 0 and 10
comb_r = [*comb]        # putting them in a list
random.shuffle(comb_r)  # shuffling the list

number_of_outputs = 10
for i in range(number_of_outputs):
    print(list(comb_r[i]))
```

Comment: This looks to be working. I'm just iterating with a large number to validate if this works as expected. I will keep you posted. Thanks.

Comment: I have increased the iteration to 100 from 10. I see this [0, 6, 10, 0, 2, 9, 8, 5, 5, 3, 1, 0, 1] gets repeated during iteration. This doesn't repeat right after but somewhere in the middle. Your example ensures the values that get generated right after (immediate).

Comment: In this case you will want another approach: iterate over the combinations. If you go completely random, some elements will eventually repeat themselves. I updated my answer. With this alternative solution, no repetition can occur.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `random.choice` to pick the numbers from a list of potential values

```
for i in range(10):
    perturbdp = random.randint(1, 12)
    nums = list(range(0, d[perturbdp])) + list(range(d[perturbdp] + 1, 11))
    d[perturbdp] = random.choice(nums)
    print(perturbdp)
    print(d)
```

Output

```
5
[0, 6, 9, 7, 2, 1, 4, 5, 3, 3, 8, 4, 2]
1
[0, 1, 9, 7, 2, 1, 4, 5, 3, 3, 8, 4, 2]
5
[0, 1, 9, 7, 2, 6, 4, 5, 3, 3, 8, 4, 2]
3
[0, 1, 9, 3, 2, 6, 4, 5, 3, 3, 8, 4, 2]
6
[0, 1, 9, 3, 2, 6, 6, 5, 3, 3, 8, 4, 2]
3
[0, 1, 9, 1, 2, 6, 6, 5, 3, 3, 8, 4, 2]
7
[0, 1, 9, 1, 2, 6, 6, 4, 3, 3, 8, 4, 2]
7
[0, 1, 9, 1, 2, 6, 6, 1, 3, 3, 8, 4, 2]
10
[0, 1, 9, 1, 2, 6, 6, 1, 3, 3, 5, 4, 2]
8
[0, 1, 9, 1, 2, 6, 6, 1, 7, 3, 5, 4, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Here the values (same string) get repeated.                                      
`7`
`[0, 10, 10, 0, 0, 2, 1, 9, 1, 3, 10, 0, 10]`
`11`
`[0, 10, 10, 0, 0, 2, 1, 9, 1, 3, 10, 0, 10]`

Comment: This doesn't prevent the new `d[perturbdp]` from being unchanged between two iterations (this was OP's expectation in my understanding of the problem at least)

Comment: @JustLearn do you mean you want every list to have unique values?

Comment: @Guy It should not repeat any of the previous 13 values in a list. In your example, 11 was picked up and it is trying to modify the 11th position with same value that was there already.

Comment: @Guy This is working. If I have to generate random number between a and b (including a, b) and multiply by 100, how can I achieve this? i tried to modify your code, and it doesn't work

Comment: @JustLearn `random.choice(nums)` returns an `int`, you can multiple that.

Comment: @Guy, `nums = list(range(pmin, p[perturbdp])) + list(range((p[perturbdp]) + 1, pmax))`           What happens if p[perturbdp] is already 4 digits and ends with 00 (pmin = 10 and pmax = 30)

Comment: @JustLearn `num` will contain the values from `list(range(pmin, p[perturbdp]))`

Comment: @Guy Yes. Let's say pmin is 1000 and p[perturbdp] is 3000. Here I am looking for values that ends in hundreds (ex 1000, 1100, 1200 ... 3000 etc.) how can I achieve this?

Comment: @JustLearn you can add the third interval parameter to `range`, `nums = list(range(pmin, 1900, 100)) + list(range(pmax + 100, 3000, 100))`

Comment: Thanks @Guy This has helped. However, does the value from the list ever gets repeated? Because I did for 100 iterations, I found all 100 unique list with 13 values.

Comment: @JustLearn yes, it might repeat.

Comment: Ok @Guy Thanks.